# How to prevent Navigation when using Android Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to check the actual Fragment if it's dirty and warn the user to lose his changes. I could'nt find an Listener on the Navcontroller to interact before the navigation happens.

I already tried to set a listener to the BottomNavigationView but the result was that the Navigation does'nt work anymore after the reset.

```
requireActivity().bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{menuItem ->
            DialogUtil.showBeforeLeaveDetailFragmentDialog(context!!){
                requireActivity().bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(null)
                findNavController().navigate(menuItem.itemId)
            }
            false
        }
```

Is there any global Listener which i can use or another clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
requireActivity().bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{menuItem ->
            DialogUtil.showBeforeLeaveDetailFragmentDialog(context!!){
                return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
            }
            false
        }
```

And I don't know why are you clearing the `NavigationItemSelectedListener`. Explain why you are doing it.